# Can't Figure Out Why My Script Isn't Able To Register Collisions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I feel like it'll help to state what my goal with this script is.
I'm trying to make a Rocket Landing game. You start on a pad and basically have a controlled fall until you land - the player can left-mouse-click to activate the thruster to move in the direction of the mouse on the screen. (I have no issues with the thruster/ physics movement in the game...just collision detection.)

This specific script is meant to:

1. Detect collision
2. Detect specifically what has been collided with. (Green, Yellow, Red Landing Pads OR Ground)
3. Immediately stop ALL physics and movement once the collision has occurred. (Think of it as becoming the background in a game/ app. Once you land, everything freezes, the game manager will show a window that displays your score, and 2 buttons to Retry or Quit.

There is a Rigidbody on the 'Rocket' BUT the 'Rocket' is an empty object that is the parent of the 'Thruster' and the 'Thruster' is the parent of the 'RocketBody'.

Rocket(Has Rigidbody, no collider)
->Thruster(No Rigidbody, has box collider)
->->RocketBody(No Rigidbody, has box collider)

Other pieces of information. The Rigidbody is dynamic, is NOT kinematic, nothing in this scenario 'IsTrigger' meaning any of the landing pads or the ground --- although I have attempted to make them all triggers to see if it'd register the collision.

I know I want to set the Rigidbody of the Rocket to be Kinematic at the moment of any collision occurring. I just can't figure out why I can't even detect a collision at all despite the Rocket having an RB.

This is the code -- I'm not super confident in my coding abilities so I do tend to kind of try everything I can and trim the fat on the back end, so I'm definitely open to the idea that I am missing something extremely basic. Sorry in advance if what you see just looks like a jumble. Also apologies but it was too much to send in a single screenshot but not enough to justify 2.

-The Code Below-

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LandingBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private bool _greenPad;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool _yellowPad;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool _redPad;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool _ground;

    private bool _crash = false;

    private float _score = 1;

    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody _rigidBody;


    private void Awake()
    {
        _rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("A collision has occurred.");

        //_rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        _rigidBody.isKinematic = false;

        if (!collision.gameObject.CompareTag("LandingPad") ||     !collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (collision.gameObject.transform.rotation.z >= 45 ||     collision.gameObject.transform.rotation.z <= -45)
        {
            _crash = true;
            
        }

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("LandingPad"))
        {
            if (_greenPad)
            {
                Debug.Log("Green Landing Pad Found."); 
                _score *= 2;      
            }

            if (_yellowPad)
            {
                Debug.Log("Yellow Landing Pad Found.");
                _score *= 3;
            }

            if (_redPad)
            {
                Debug.Log("Red Landing Pad Found.");
                _score *= 5;
            }
        }

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Ground Found.");
            _score *= 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to check the collision mask. Objects will not collide if their layers are not set to collide. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Comment: Try changing OnCollisionEnter to OnTriggerEnter, and set the collider to isTrigger for collider being triggered.

Comment: `Collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached.`  It sounds like you do not have a collider that also has a rigidbody.  I suggest adding the collider to your Rocket object.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both the rocket and pads have colliders not marked as triggers, and that the tags are placed correctly in the objects that actually have the colliders